# How to run Android app or install on PlayStore if unavailable for API30?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-install-apk, android-package-managers

I have a android app where I want to run other apps. If these apps are not installed already, I would like to open PlayStore to let the user install them:

```
var info : ApplicationInfo? = null
try {
    info = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0) as ApplicationInfo
} catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException){
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.data = Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName")
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    context.startActivity(intent)
}

if (info != null) {
    val intent = pm.getintentForPackage(packageName) as Intent
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

This snippet works so far good for API 26 (Android 8) for instance. But for API 30 (Android 11) the `getApplicationInfo()` throws a `NameNotFoundException` always, even when I already installed the app.

**Whats wrong here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[On Android 11](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility), methods on `PackageManager` like `getApplicationInfo()` no longer work by default. You need to either:

- Not call them, or
- Add a `<queries>` element to your manifest, whitelisting the third-party apps that you wish to find, or
- Request the `MANAGE_ALL_APPS` permission (and run the risk of your app being banned from the Play Store)

In your case, [the `<queries>` element](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility#package-name) is probably a safe choice, assuming that your list of application IDs that you are looking for is knowable at compile time.